# Определение собственных событий в классе

Tags: javascript

Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как создавать подобные классы с колбэками? То есть как определить свой класс, в котором будут определены события, на которые можно повесить обработчики. Как инициировать событие? Пробовал начать так:

```
function Make(){
    this.onstart = function(){

   }
    this.onend = function(){

    }
}
```

Но дальше что делать не знаю. Как реализовать подобную функциональность?

Comment: А что именно вы хотите получить? И как оно должно работать?

Comment: ничего, мне просто было интересно как это реализовывается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе вы правильно мыслите. Чтобы создать определенные события в классе, надо просто завести переменные для обработчиков этих событий (или массивы если обработчиков планируется несколько. При запуске определенной функции объекта надо проверять соответствующий обработчик и, если он определен - запускать его.

Например так:

```
function CallBackObject () {
    this.onstart = null;
    this.onend = null;
}

CallBackObject.prototype = {
    doSomething: function() {
        if(this.onstart) { // если есть обработчики
            this.onstart(); // инициировать событие
        } 

        // какой-то код

        if(this.onend) {
            this.onend();
        }
    }
};
```

Соответственно, если обработчиков много, то надо завести массив для их хранения и определить свою функцию `addEventListener` или другую какую, и при инициации события вызывать их последовательно один за другим.

Можно обработчики передавать как параметры в конструктор, а можно и просто присвоить свойству

`cbo.onstart = function() { /* код */}`

Answer (score 0):

Советую так же посмотреть в сторону Backbone. Там хорошо прописано как работать с событиями. Даже если не хотите использовать, то посмотрите исходники, как это делают другие, чужой опыт, тоже хорошо.

[backbonejs.org](http://backbonejs.org)